# Why is my component rendered twice in react.js 16.x?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my simple component that rerendered twice when open the page:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function TestComponent() {
      console.log("test component rendered")
      
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    
      return (
        <div>
          TEST COMPONENT
        </div>
      )
}
```

That happens in v16.13.1 but works fine in v.17.0.1. Is there a way to fix it in v16.x?

Comment: Are you using React's strict mode?

Comment: React.memo() doesn't help

Comment: ...OK. Are you using [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)?

Comment: yes. I do.. <React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i guess if you still used React 16.x is to go with class based component and control the render by overriding shouldComponentUpdate method.

The problem is with React16.x not you or your component :-)